# Installing Erlang/OTP 17.5 on OSX

Tags: erlang, installation

The [official install instructions](http://www.erlang.org/doc/installation_guide/INSTALL.html#Advanced-configuration-and-build-of-ErlangOTP_Building_OS-X-Darwin) say:

> If you want to build the wx application, you will need to get
>   wxWidgets-3.0 (wxWidgets-3.0.0.tar.bz2 from
>   http://sourceforge.net/projects/wxwindows/files/3.0.0/) or get it from
>   github with bug fixes:
>
> ```
> $ git clone --branch WX_3_0_branch git@github.com:wxWidgets/wxWidgets.git
> ```

Who wouldn't want bug fixes:

```
$ git clone --branch WX_3_0_branch git@github.com:wxWidgets/wxWidgets.git
Cloning into 'wxWidgets'...
fatal: Remote branch WX_3_0_branch not found in upstream origin
```

Does anyone know where the bug fix version is located?

**Response to comment**:

With all caps, I get:

```
$ git clone --branch WX_3_0_BRANCH git@github.com:wxWidgets/wxWidgets.git
Cloning into 'wxWidgets'...
ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

For future searchers: in order to use github commands like above, [you need to setup ssh keys for your computer](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys/).  I had already done that, but for some reason it didn't work a few hours later.  Firewall problems at my new location? I don't know.  I moved to a different location/server from where I was getting the `Connection reset by peer` error, and then I created a new ssh key, and I was able to download and install wxWidgets.  The `git clone` command just downloads the source, so you probably want to be at the `~/Downloads` prompt when you issue that command.  The Erlang install directions tell you how to install wxWidgets.

Comment: It's `WX_3_0_BRANCH` (all uppercase).

Comment: @SteveVinoski, Thanks for taking a look.  That also produces an error--see the bottom of my post.

Comment: That just means you're not set up to be able to use that form of git URL. Try `git://github.com/wxWidgets/wxWidgets.git` instead.

Comment: @SteveVinoski,  Thanks for the quick response!  I've been checking on my end, and I seem to be having trouble with an ssh key that I set up this morning.  I keep getting a `Connection reset by peer` error when reaching out to github from the command line, e.g. `$ ssh -T git@github.com`  I'll have to get that problem sorted.

Comment: @SteveVinoski, I managed to get my ssh key working with git, then I was able to clone and install wxWidgets, then install Erlang.  Thanks!  Can you move your comment to an answer, so that I can mark the question solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The branch in question is named `WX_3_0_BRANCH` — all uppercase.